# How to cancel a pending charge?

Tags: shopify

As subject, I created a RecurringApplicationCharge object and want to destroy it. The API response says the object should be activated before cancelling it but the object is in pending state. How could I destroy the object without noticing the store owner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a recurring application charge is pending, then you can just leave it alone and Shopify will delete it after 48 hours.